# implement segmentUI android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the segmentUI found in the ios sdk in android. I have been able to determine that I need to use the radiogroup. My query is how to effectively implement this idea. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create 9patch images corresponding to each individual segment, that is, left, center and right and then implement the radiobutton UI which you can position using xml.